# OS notification in gulp-notify doesn't work

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-notify

### Hi everyone

I have a custom error handler that's supposed to show a notification with gulp-notify and then log it in the console when sass compiler **fail**.

```
var errorHandler = function(error) {
    notify.onError({
        title: 'Task Failed [' + error.plugin + ']',
        message: 'Sass ha ricontrato un errore',
        sound: true
    })(error);
    this.emit('end');
    notify("Files has an error");
    return notify().write(error);
};

function scss() {
    return src("product-template/Product Template/assets/styles/scss/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .on("error", errorHandler)
        .pipe(prefix(/*{grid: "no-autoplace"}*/))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(dest("./product-template/Product Template/assets/styles/css/"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

#### Expected behavior

This piece of code supposed to, when sass has an error, to show a notification  Os (windows) message (toast) with a title, body ecc

#### Real behavior

The piece of code actualy doesn't work it only log the message of error in the console. Don't the expected behavior

---

#### **is there any error in the configuration?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function scss() {
    return src("product-template/Product Template/assets/styles/scss/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .on("error", function(error) {
            notify.onError({
                title: 'Task Failed [' + error.plugin + ']',
                message: 'Sass ha ricontrato un errore',
                sound: true
            })(error);
            this.emit('end');
            notify("Files has an error");
            return notify().write(error);
        })
        .pipe(prefix(/*{grid: "no-autoplace"}*/))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(dest("./product-template/Product Template/assets/styles/css/"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but nothing change. I think that the problem is in Windows, because certain times I receive the notification from gulp, and certain times nothing

Comment: Interesting, my answer is working correctly in my machine, but I am on a mac, it could very well be a windows issue.